# All json objects get updated on text change?

Tags: java, android, json, textwatcher

> This is my log for the 1st text change

```
[{
    "custInfo": "Anup 8600931386",
    "rate": "24032",
    "weight": "21.00000",
    "makingAmt": "232",
    "description": "GENTS ANGTHI 22k NO STONE",
    "sum_total": "50954.4",
    "vat": "",
    "itemTotal": "50954.4",
    "barcode": "BQSP78BB",
    "net_rate": "24264.0",
    "date": "09-12-2015",
    "invoiceNo": "1",
    "bill_type": "Estimate"
}]
```

> Now when I add one more entry the previous item also gets updated.This is the log after the 2nd entry.

```
[{
    "custInfo": "Anup 8600931386",
    "rate": "24052",
    "weight": "12.00000",
    "makingAmt": "228",
    "description": "LADIES TOP 22K NO STONE",
    "sum_total": "29136.0",
    "vat": "",
    "itemTotal": "29136.0",
    "barcode": "BQSP82BB",
    "net_rate": "24280.0",
    "date": "09-12-2015",
    "invoiceNo": "1",
    "bill_type": "Estimate"
}, {
    "custInfo": "Anup 8600931386",
    "rate": "24052",
    "weight": "12.00000",
    "makingAmt": "228",
    "description": "LADIES TOP 22K NO STONE",
    "sum_total": "29136.0",
    "vat": "",
    "itemTotal": "29136.0",
    "barcode": "BQSP82BB",
    "net_rate": "24280.0",
    "date": "09-12-2015",
    "invoiceNo": "1",
    "bill_type": "Estimate"
}]
```

> This is my text watcher implementation and the code that updates the values is inside after text changed().

```
private TextWatcher mkAmountTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String mkAmt = makingAmount.getText().toString();
            mk = Double.parseDouble(mkAmt);
            calculateAndShow(wt, rt, mk);

            int mid = (int) newRow.getTag()-1;
            if ((mid<0) || (mid>itemSelectedJson.length())){
                return;
            }
            try{
                itemSelectedJson.getJSONObject(mid).put("makingAmt",mkAmt);

                Log.d("MAKING_TW", itemSelectedJson.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
```

> This is the code for creating the json array.

```
 private void createJsonArray() {
    billType = (invEstSwitch.isChecked() ? textViewEstimate : textViewInvoice)
            .getText().toString();
    String invNumber = textViewInvNo.getText().toString();
    String bcode = barCode.getText().toString();
    String description = itemDesc.getText().toString();
    String wt = weightLine.getText().toString();
    String rateAmt = rateAmount.getText().toString();
    String making = makingAmount.getText().toString();
    String netr = netRate.getText().toString();
    String iTotal = itemtotal.getText().toString();
    String vatAmt = textViewVat.getText().toString();
    String sumAmt = textViewSum.getText().toString();
    String crtDate = textViewCurrentDate.getText().toString();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("custInfo", custSelected.toString());
        jsonObject.put("invoiceNo", invNumber);
        jsonObject.put("barcode", bcode);
        jsonObject.put("description", description);
        jsonObject.put("weight", wt);
        jsonObject.put("rate", rateAmt);
        jsonObject.put("makingAmt", making);
        jsonObject.put("net_rate", netr);
        jsonObject.put("itemTotal", iTotal);
        jsonObject.put("vat", vatAmt);
        jsonObject.put("sum_total", sumAmt);
        jsonObject.put("bill_type", billType);
        jsonObject.put("date", crtDate);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {

        itemSelectedJson.put(index, jsonObject);
        index++;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this Method `createJsonArray()` you are not using same JSONObject every time. That's why you are getting same content again and again.

Just try to initialize `jsonObject`  in `createJsonArray()` method first, then I guess, it will work.